# SVG Animation does not fill container in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, framer-motion

I'm having issues with SVG animation not filling whole container on Safari browser. For some reason on Safari width of my SVG seems to bo random, but it works fine on Chrome and other browsers.

**Expected behavior:**

- After clicking menu icon, SVG background animation should fill container with red borders.

**Actual behavior**

- Animation does not fill whole container on Safari Mac / iOS

**Codepen**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/safari-broken-svg-animation-yzfe3

Simplified code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

function MenuOverlay({ isOpen, firstLoad }) {
  const controls = useAnimation();

  const variants = {
    open: {
      d: [
        "M 0 24 L 0 0 L 1 0 C 1 8 1 16 1 24 L 0 24 Z",
        "M 0 24 L 0 0 L 9.143 0 C 18.286 0 18.286 24 9.143 24 L 0 24 Z",
        "M 0 24 L 0 0 L 24 0 C 24 8 24 16 24 24 L 0 24 Z",
      ],
      scaleX: [0, 1, 1],
      transition: {
        ease: ["easeIn", "easeOut"],
      },
    },
    close: {
      d: [
        "M 0 24 L 0 0 L 24 0 C 24 8 24 16 24 24 L 0 24 Z",
        "M 0 24 L 0 0 L 16.5 0 C 9 5.5 8.5 17.5 16.5 24 L 0 24 Z",
        "M 0 24 L 0 0 L 1 0 C 1 8 1 16 1 24 L 0 24 Z",
      ],
      scaleX: [1, 1, 0],
      transition: {
        ease: ["easeIn", "easeOut"],
      },
    },
  };

  // Sequence animation
  async function open() {
    await controls.start("open");
  }
  async function close() {
    await controls.start("close");
  }

  if (!firstLoad) {
    isOpen ? open() : close();
  }

  return (
    <LazyMotion features={domAnimation}>
      <Container>
        <Svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <Path animate={controls} variants={variants} />
        </Svg>
      </Container>
    </LazyMotion>
  );
}

export default MenuOverlay;

// Styled Components
const Container = styled(m.div)`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
`;

const Svg = styled.svg`
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Mobile */
  width: 100vw;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  /* Tablet */
  @media screen and (min-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints[0]}) {
    width: 75vw;
    transform: unset;
  }
  /* Desktop */
  @media screen and (min-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints[1]}) {
    width: 50vw;
  }
`;
const Path = styled(m.path)`
  fill: ${({ theme }) => theme.black[1]};
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the WebKit version of transform before where you have transform: scaleX(-1);

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
```

Can you also provide us with a codepen or a link to where you have it so we can better see the behavior?

Ok after looking at your code try modifying you SVG view box from

```
<Svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

to

```
<Svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

Comment: I have updated question with demo link where this behavior occurs. I have also tried Your solution but unfortunately it doesn't fix my issue. I'll update this thread with codepen soon.

demo: https://piwnice-prod.netlify.app/menu-animation/

Thanks

Comment: I have made a codepen example, link below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/safari-broken-svg-animation-yzfe3

Comment: Modified my response above, also testing it works fine with your code after it has been browser cached but the moment I clear cache it does it again, try the view box change I added above that is more safari friendly and let me know.

Comment: Thank You! I actually fixed my issue, although I don't understand exactly why safari was rendering it so weirdly before ?

Comment: Safari is a little more precise with SVG than others so your path was growing up to the original width it probably was made to so sometimes playing with the viewbox size could fix those glitches.

Comment: Thank You once again, I was struggling with this issue for last three days ( obviously not all the time, but i was clearly stuck. I have even tried playing with viewbox but in wrong way )